# Do heroes themselves count as a percentage of the base you are attacking?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Do heroes themselves count as a percentage of the base you are attacking? Or do you just have to destroy their "altars"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Enemy heroes don't count as a percentage of the base as they are not "still tiles" themselves.

You just have to destroy the altars. I have won a battle (100%) where the enemy hero was still living, after his altar got destroyed.